# ng-model is not updated when ng-options changes AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My `optionType` is not getting updated when I change the value in the dropdown.

```
<select ng-model="optionType" ng-options="op.option for op in ops" ng-change="optionChanged()"></select>
```

I use `ng-change` to check for the value change. I put a break point at the top of `optionChanged()` and see that the value of `optionType` is not changed when the function is called.

```
.controller('uploadCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ops = [ 
        { option: "Report" }, 
        { option: "Support" }, 
        { option: "Learn" } 
    ] ;

    $scope.optionType = $scope.ops[0];

    $scope.optionChanged = function() {

    };
})
```

Comment: I don't understand where is your problem, dude, but here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/6HnbRA?p=preview that works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try following it will print selected value in console

```
$scope.optionChanged = function() 
{
    console.log($scope.optionType.option);
};
```

Comment: @PTN what are trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ng-selected`:

HTML

```
<select ng-model="optionType" ng-options="op.option for op in ops" ng-selected="optionSelected(optionType)"></select>
```

JS

```
.controller('uploadCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ops = [ 
        { option: "Report" }, 
        { option: "Support" }, 
        { option: "Learn" } 
    ] ;

    $scope.optionType = $scope.ops[0];

    $scope.optionSelected = function(option) {
          $scope.optionType = option;
          //if the above doesn't work, tell me your console values
          console.log($scope.optionType); //or
          alert($scope.optionType);
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a scope issue. Either bind with $parent, like this: `ng-model="$parent.optionType"`, or put your variable within an object:

JS:

```
$scope.option = { optionType: $scope.ops[0] };
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="option.optionType" ng-options="op.option for op in ops" ng-change="optionChanged()"></select>
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes